# Visual Studio Code OmniSharp offline installation?

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm on computer that doesn't have access to internet, I've installed Visual Studio Code x64, downloaded latest OmniSharp build x64, dropped OmniSharp to Program Files, added OmniSharp to PATH, installed VSCode OmniSharp extension, added "omnisharp.path" to config, however the extension still tryies to download OmniSharp from the internet and not using local installation. What should I do?

EDIT: I tried downloading the OmniSharp ZIP-file from exact location that is written in package.json file and droping it to .omnisharp folder in .vscode\extensions folder, but it still tries to download it.

Comment: Every time I debug it downloads. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Just download from some station with access to internet

0. Download vscode [setup](https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/493869ee8e8a846b0855873886fc79d480d342de/VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.26.1.exe) or [portable one](https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/493869ee8e8a846b0855873886fc79d480d342de/VSCode-win32-x64-1.26.1.zip)
   install setup or extract portable where you want
   lanch it.
1. Download [omnisharp](https://vsdebugger.blob.core.windows.net/coreclr-debug-1-12-5/coreclr-debug-win7-x64.zip) and [debugger](https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/493869ee8e8a846b0855873886fc79d480d342de/VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.26.1.exe) and extract it to

1. *%UserProfile%.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2.omnisharp\1.30.1*
2. *%UserProfile%.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2.debugger*

respectively according to paths in config *.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.15.2\package.json*

**Upd**: with time location switched to :

1. *%USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.3.omnisharp\1.37.2*
2. *%USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.3.debugger*

respectively and **replace** file **install.Begin** with **install.Lock** in this folders

Comment: I'm behind a proxy. This isn't working for me. Problem still exists.

Comment: @Wido, dude, pls, try again with finalization (sealing) folders with lock file described - and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

update manualy below folders with your versions and add an install.Lock empty file in the folders. and restart vs code.

.debugger
.omnisharp
.razor

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The VSCode Extensions for offline installation are now available at

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases